# How can I hide all errors from an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors

I have taken a huge project from one of my friends and I just want to view the files just to understand some coding architectures they have implemented. On my system I don't have those jars and complete code so my Eclipse is showing almost 10,000 errors. Now I am still able to go through the code but the red errors are not allowing me to concentrate well. How can I hide all the errors in this particular project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can hide all the errors but you can

- limit the number of reported problems in `Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Building`, or
- exlude all the files from your build path folder (`Java Build Path -> Souce -> Select source folder and Edit... -> Enter folder name and press Next -> Add '**' as Exclusion pattern`)

Comment: This is ok but not what I desire since if I remove it from build path I lose the important feature "ctrl+click". so I have to manually open the files which again becomes inconvenient

Comment: I tried changing Compiler preference and minimize the no. of errors to 1. A same import error its showing in all the files but thats ok. And control+click feature works in this case :) . The Compiler preference is workspace dependent and not project dependent but anyways I created a new workspace for this project so it works for me so I will accept ur ans. thanks Claszen.

Comment: @weakstudent I agree that both solutions are not perfect for your use case - but I could not find any other. Regarding the compiler preference I can open the project properties and "enable project specific settings" for the "Building" preference page (eclipse Indigo).

Comment: Ohh ya. Sry I saw my project properties but did not check the checkbox and overlooked it. Its sufficient for my purpose. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable `JavaBuilder` in `Properties -> Builders`. Sometimes after disabling `JavaBuilder` error status is not updated (they are still visible). In that case do the following:

1. In `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source` remove source folder(s)
2. Clear project using `Build -> Clear...`
3. Disable `JavaBuilder` as described above
4. Add source folder(s) again

That way you should not be irritated with error messages any longer, but retaining all the possibilities to navigate by ctrl+click, search references etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way , just a workaround if you just want to browse the source code and not worried about compile and building it.

You just need to remove the source folder in the java build path , this will help you to get rid of those red errors that clutter your source.

**Right click on Project->Properties->Java Build Path->in Source tab select your source folder and click remove.**

**Restart your eclipse.**

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, go on any class. Right click on the red marks shown on the vertical ruler and disable the 3 options. See below.

[image]