# How can I pretty-print multiple Java files to a single page?

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, pretty-print

I am a teacher and would like my students to have in front of them pretty printouts of the source code to 4 short Java files.  I don't want to waste paper (or have them shuffling papers around), so I would like to have the four files on a single page.  I don't want to print (from Eclipse) each to a separate PDF, then combine them 4-up, since that would make the text tiny.  I tried concatenating the four files into a single .java file in Eclipse, but, despite reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014223/how-can-i-hide-all-errors-from-an-eclipse-project), I found no way of suppressing the display of errors (namely defining multiple public classes in a single file).

Update: I don't just want to print the code as text.  I would like it pretty-printed, i.e., with syntax highlighting.

Comment: If I understand the question right, I'd paste in LibreOffice and set up 4 columns of text. And maybe set horizontal page orientation.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to pretty-print them, i.e., have syntax-based coloring, etc.

Comment: *"so I would like to have the four files on a single page."*  How about having the source code on the tablet of every student?  Scribing the codes on dead tree seems so ..last millennium.  What's next, marks scratched into rocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can copy them from eclipse to open/libreoffice or word to keep the formatting, especially the colors.
- You could use a program like Highlight: http://www.andre-simon.de/ (Results can be copied to with highlighting)
- You could use Latex to handle the formatting
- You could put the source together in one file, you have to make the necessary changes to make sure there is only one public class:

  public class a {}

  class B {}

Comment: I regret that I can only mark this correct once.  I went with the first, even though I lost the line numbers.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, you can not directly copy the line numbers, only with some strange ways. I prefer to set line numbers in open/libreoffice or word. Try a short google search for "line numbering <software>", there are lots of information for this.

Comment: I'd want to restart with each file, so the line numbering software wouldn't do it for me, at least not in a single step.

Comment: For Word (2010), you can choose "restart at each section". You just add a section break behind every file and you start with 1 again. For Openoffice/Libreoffice, you can format the current paragraph and check "Restart at this paragraph". Thats more than 1 step, but still quite easy and fast if you know where to click.

Comment: Thanks, you have tons of great ideas.  I look forward to telling people that I knew you back when your SO reputation was only three digits. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Copy them all, to a text editor, and print from there.