# How to prevent Eclipse from displaying error dialogs

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse displays an error every several seconds (!) during my work. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYmwB.png.
I want to completely prevent Eclipse from displaying errors in a separate windows and thus distracting me from the work. I want all the errors silently go to the logs. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide all errors from an Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014223/how-can-i-hide-all-errors-from-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: No, it is not. The question you're referring to deals with the errors in a program, while mine question deals with the errors of Eclipse by itself. See my screenshot.

Comment: ARE YOU RUNNING IN TEST ENVIRONMENT?

Comment: No, I use default configuration

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) states that in the Runtime Options there is an option:

```
  -launcher.suppressErrors (Executable)
```

"If specified the executable will not display any error or message dialogs.  This is useful if the executable is being used in an unattended situation."

so just set that

Comment: UPD: no, unfortunately that didn't work. After few minutes - same problem.